# how to call particular index of an array in main when array is declared in separate class in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to print the 3rd index of an array ......
what is the  syntax for it...
package javaapplication2;
import java.util.*;

public class a {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   students s =new students();
    System.out.println(""+s.array[3]);

}
static class students{
     int array[] = new int[10];
    int a=1990;
    public void rollno (){

    for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
    {

       array[i]=a;
       a++;

    }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the 3rd item in an array you do

```
System.out.println(""+s.array[2]);
```

because indices start at `0`.

However the main problem here appears to be that you don't ever call `rollno()`, so the array remains filled with zeros.

Just do `s.rollno();` before `println`.